# WPF Templates. Template Selector does not receive item

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

My current problem is that i have two templates which should be selected via a template selector.
I have defined two datatemplates. Each containing different stackPanel, different in the sense that the count of the containing elements differs.

But in my Template Selector i cannot select one of the templates because the item given to the SelectTemplate method is always null.

I assume have not understood how templates do work in wpf. The examples you see on microsfts

Here you can see how i defined my datatemplates

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Any">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                 <Label>Test</Label>
                 <Label>Test</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Non" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Label>Test</Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <selector:HeaderSelector 
            x:Key="ContentSelector"
            AnyTemplate="{StaticResource Any}"
            NonTemplate="{StaticResource Non}"/>

</UserControl.Resources>
```

The User control defines a ScrollView. In this ScrollVewi I have placed a ContentPresenter which in turn uses my template selector.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
       <ContentPresenter 
           ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentSelector}" 
           DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyProductFilerView, Path=HasAny}" 
          />

    </ScrollViewer>
```

The Selector is called. My breakpoint gets hit. but the item parameter of the SelectTemplate method is always null. Therefor i cannot decide which template i should select.

```
public class  Selector : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        public DataTemplate NonTemplate { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate  AnyTemplate { get; set; }



        public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            switch (item)
            {

                default:
                    return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
            }

        }
    }
```

- **Could you explain why item is always null in my example?**
- *And maybe describe what needs to be done to fill item with a value?*

Comment: It's called ContentTemplateSelector because it selects the ContentTemplate, i.e. the DataTemplate used to display the Content property. Which you haven't set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding to or set the `DataContext` property of the `ContentPresenter`, you should use the `Content` property:

```
 <ContentPresenter 
       ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentSelector}" 
       Content="{Binding ElementName=MyProductFilerView, Path=HasAny}" />
```

You could bind `Content` directly to the `DataContext` like this:

```
<ContentPresenter 
       ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentSelector}" 
       DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyProductFilerView, Path=HasAny}"
       Content="{Binding} "/>
```